# Quicker (and more Pythonic) solution than re.sub? Remove prefix (consisting of many identical characters)

Tags: python, regex, performance, replace, slice

I am trying to remove a prefix from a given string, which contains an unknown length of contiguous 'X' characters. In most cases, this prefix will be thousands of characters long. The first solution I thought of was to use regex -

`str = re.sub(r'X*', '', str)`

An obvious alternative (and faster) solution is to iterate over each character until it `is not 'X'`, and slice accordingly, but this is bulky and the character iteration doesn't seem Pythonic?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply use [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "X"*1000+"Y"*10000
>>> %timeit re.sub(r'X*', '', a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 940 µs per loop
>>> %timeit a.lstrip("X")
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.04 µs per loop
>>> a.lstrip("X") == re.sub(r'X*', '', a)
True
```

Note that if the string contains Xs that *aren't* part of a prefix, that `re.sub` call will remove them, so it might not be what you want in any case.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Kudos for the benchmarking too :) No idea how I overlooked this in the standard library....

Answer (score 1):

This is in the standard library: `string.lstrip(s, 'X')`.